# How to convert value of Generic Type Argument to a concrete type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to convert the value of the generic type parameter T value into integer after making sure that T is in fact integer:

```
public class Test
{
    void DoSomething<T>(T value)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            int x = (int)value; // Error 167 Cannot convert type 'T' to 'int'
            int y = (int)(object)value; // works though boxing and unboxing
        }
    }
}
```

Although it works through boxing and unboxing, this is an additional performance overhead and i was wandering if there's a way to do it directly.

Comment: So, let me understand this... You are constructing a method that is generic, but it needs to know if the type parameter is an int?  Your design, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Any reason to not add an overload `void DoSomething(int value){}` ?

Comment: This is a simplified example. Actual code has lots of stuff before and after conversion which benefit from generics

Comment: T is already int, why are you trying to cast it anyway? It doesnt make sense

Comment: @Will There are plenty of cases where you want to have a generic method that behaves slightly differently for a certain subset of types but still uses 99% of the generic method's generic logic. There is nothing wrong with this design.

Comment: @Slight plenty of bad cases that have bad designs, sure.  Plenty of those around.

Comment: `T` may be an enumerated type that has an underlying `int`. It could also be a more complex type that is convertible to an `int` (would have to modify type check in this case).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing is going to be the most efficient way here, to be honest. I don't know of any way of avoiding the boxing occurring, and any other form of conversion (e.g. Convert.ToInt32) is potentially going to perform conversions you don't actually want.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts on boxing/unboxing. Calling Convert would indeed be slower as there's an added overhead of calling as well as the boxing/unboxing that would occur anyway: Convert.ToInt32(object value) takes object so T would be boxed at this point and then unboxed at some point later.

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = (dynamic)MyTest.Value;
```

I know this is a very old thread, but this is the actual way to do it. `(dynamic)` will convert the T value to any of the primitive known type in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

int and the other CLR primitives implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx).

```
public class Test
{
    void DoSomething<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            int y = value.ToInt32(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098316/1458303. It contains an effective class implementation which avoids boxing during conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id = (dynamic)myobject.SingleOrDefault();
```

OR

```
int id = (int)myobject.SingleOrDefault();
```

It worked for me to get the `int` value. Here `myobject` is having `ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>` value.

Answer (score 0):

The following way should work.

```
int x = (int)(value as int?);
```