# Handling interactions between generic and static types

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a generic method where I would like a different execution path to occur based on the type of the generic Type parameter. The different execution paths are statically typed, e.g.

```
public static T Get<T>(this NameValueCollection collection, string name) where T : struct
{
    //Perform test on type, if it matches, delegate to statically typed method.
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)GetInt32(collection, name);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime)) return (T) (object) GetDateTime(collection, name);

    //Other types parsed here...

    //If nothing matched, return default.
    return default(T);
}
```

The only way I've found to be able to use the return result of the static execution path is to box it as an object, and then cast it to 'T'.

To me this defeats the purpose of using a generic method in the first place (other than gaining some syntactical sugar). Does anyone know a way of being able to return the int value as T, in cases where we have already established that T is of type int?

I was looking at using a var of type 'dynamic' but read that it just end sup using object behind the scenes anyway.

Is this, perhaps, the extent of generics?

--

Updated to include my final approach, based on smartcaveman's reply, which uses the type resolution of generic static classes to determine which 'parsing' method to use, without boxing or using dynamic.

```
public class StringParser
{
    private class Getter<T>
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<StringParser, Getter<T>> Getters = new ConcurrentDictionary<StringParser, Getter<T>>();

        public Func<string, T> Get { get; set; }

        private Getter() {}

        public static Getter<T> For(StringParser stringParser)
        {
            return Getters.GetOrAdd(stringParser, x => new Getter<T>());
        }
    }

    public virtual T Get<T>(string value)
    {
        var get = Getter<T>.For(this).Get;

        if (get == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No 'get' has been configured for values of type '{0}'.", typeof (T).Name));

        return get(value);
    }

    public void SetupGet<T>(Func<string, T> get)
    {
        Getter<T>.For(this).Get = get;
    }
}
```

Fairly simple to use:

```
public static void Usage()
{
    StringParser parser = new StringParser();
    parser.SetupGet(Int32.Parse);            
    int myInt = parser.Get<int>("3");            
}
```

The trick of smartcaveman's method is that generic static classes with different type parameters are actually considered different Types, and do not share static members.

Very cool stuff, thank you!

Comment: Note the difference, in my example, calls to Configure are static and applied globally. This leads to less code and means that you don't have to set up each parser for each instance.  However, it is based on an assumption that instances will not parse the same value type differently in different contexts (which may or may not be applicable to your use case).  An ideal solution would probably be a hybrid: it would default to the local (instance-scoped) configuration, fallback first to the global/static configuration, and as a last resort, fallback to default(T) .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast a value of generic type T to double without boxing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343551/how-to-cast-a-value-of-generic-type-t-to-double-without-boxing)

Comment: @nawfal, similar, addressing the key core principle (generic type inference), but I think my question is from a different use case, where instead of converting a generic type to a known type, we're converting a known type (string) to any arbitrary generic type (T).

Comment: @Martaver oh yes, I missed that generic part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can use a strongly typed keyed collection (e.g. `Dictionary<string,int>`), you're going to have to box the value.  There is not a work around.

That being said, it is not clear how your method is anymore useful than a non-generic version.  I'm not seeing the calling code, but it seems like the only relevant case is the int, since every other case just returns the default value.

Also, you're correct about `dynamic`.

### Update

The idea of using a dictionary would apply if there were not multiple possible types of value.  However, if there were only 1 possible type of value (e.g. int) then you could use a `Dictionary<string,int>` instead of a `NameValueCollection`.

I wrote a small sample that might give you ideas as to how you could keep strong typing with a custom class.  I have omitted null-checking and argument validation logic, and this has neither been tested nor compiled.  However, the basic idea should be clear.  You could use the `ValueRegistry` class with your `NameValueCollection` as follows.

```
 //  around application start, configure the way values are retrieved   
 //  from names for different types.  Note that this doesn't need to use
 //  a NameValueCollection, but I did so to stay consistent.

 var collection = new NameValueCollection();
 ValueRegistry.Configure<int>(name => GetInt32(collection,name));
 ValueRegistry.Configure<DateTime>(name => GetDateTime(collection,name));

 // where you are going to need to get values
 var values = new ValueRegistry();      
 int value = values.Get<int>("the name"); // nothing is boxed

public class ValueRegistry
{
       private class Provider<T> 
            where T : struct
       {
             private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ValueRegistry,Provider<T>> Providers = new ConcurrentDictionary<ValueRegistry,Provider<T>>();
              public static Provider<T> For(ValueRegistry registry)
              {
                  return Providers.GetOrAdd(registry, x => new Provider<T>());
              }
              private Provider(){
                 this.entries = new Dictionary<string,T>();
              }
              private readonly Dictionary<string,T> entries;
              private static Func<string,T> CustomGetter;
              public static void Configure(Func<string,T> getter) { CustomGetter = getter;}

              public static T GetValueOrDefault(string name)
              {
                   T value;
                    if(!entries.TryGetValue(name, out value))
                       entries[name] = value = CustomGetter != null ? CustomGetter(name) : default(T);
                     return value;
              }
       }

       public T Get<T>(string name) 
          where T : struct
       {
           return Provider<T>.For(this).GetValueOrDefault(name);
       }

       public static void Configure<T>(Func<string,T> customGetter)
                  where T : struct
       {
          Provider<T>.Configure(customGetter);      
       }

}
```

Comment: The goal of my method is to be able to wrap parsing code for various types obtained from a NameValueCollection. In real world applications, it will choose from a list of types, performing different parsing code for each. I'll update the code in the question to better demonstrate this.  Do you think you can expand on what you mean with the Dictionary?

Comment: ingenious use of generic static classes there! I'd completely forgotten about this trick. Can you expand a little on why you chose ConcurrentDictionary instead of a regular dictionary?

Comment: @Martaver - 2 reasons, 1. One value registry should only have one provider per concrete value type.  Using ConcurrentDictionary ensures this invariant in a multi-threaded environment.  It's like how you check for null, lock, then check for null again before creating an instance of a singleton.  2. GetOrAdd syntax is more concise, but if it weren't for reason #1, you could just use an extension method for the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of dispatch is possible using dynamic features introduced in C# 4.0 (and next versions support it too).

This code does what you've expressed here:

```
public static T Get<T>(this NameValueCollection collection, string name) where T : struct
{
    T v = default(T);
    dynamic indicator = v;

    return GetValue(collection, name, indicator);
}

static int GetValue(NameValueCollection collection, string name, int indicator)
{
    return 110;
}

static DateTime GetValue(NameValueCollection collection, string name, DateTime indicator)
{
    return DateTime.Now;
}

// ... other helper parsers

// if nothing else matched
static object GetValue(NameValueCollection collection, string name, object indicator)
{
    return indicator;
}
```

To perform a smoke test:

```
Console.WriteLine(Get<int>(null, null));
Console.WriteLine(Get<DateTime>(null, null));
Console.WriteLine(Get<double>(null, null));
```

Comment: Upvoted this, because it's a really great way of using a dynamic type to dispatch functionality based on a type. I also liked that it handles arguments of the same type dynamically. However, I ended up going with smartcaveman's answer since it's purely generic and achieves the same thing quite elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to box (cast value type to object) explicitly before casting it to generic T even you have stated `where T : struct`. You can do something like below but I can not say it is more elegant.

```
return (T) Convert.ChangeType(GetInt32(collection, name), typeof (int));
```

Comment: Great to know about Convert.ChangeType, I was always wondering what the best way to explicitly work with the IConvertible interface was. Unfortunately, the arguments for ChangeType just end up boxing the return result of GetInt32, so if we use this we just end up doing a whole lot more work for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary` to handle this.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<NameValueCollection, string, T>> _typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, Func<NameValueCollection, string, T>>();

static Constructor()
{
    _typeMap[typeof(DateTime)] = (nvc, name) => { return (T)GetDateTime(nvc, name); };
    // etc
}


public static T Get<T>(this NameValueCollection collection, string name) where T : struct
{
    return _typeMap[typeof(T)](collection, name);
}
```