# Prevent implicit cast to int when asking for Expression<Func<T, decimal>>

Tags: c#

So, `int` is implicitly convertible to `decimal`. This causes an issue when wanting an `Expression` of a `decimal` property, where an `Expression` of an `int` property with an implicit cast is passed instead. Due to the implicit cast, no compiler error is given.

Eg:

```
class Thing {
   public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}

void DoSomething(
   Expression<Func<Thing, decimal>> pDecimalExpression
) {
   ...
}

DoSomething(t => t.IntProperty); // compiles; IntProperty is implicitly cast to decimal
```

Is there a way at compile time that I can ensure I'm really getting a `decimal` property? I would like a compiler error if I pass an expression with an implicit cast in it like this.

(Since I'm using reflection, I end up with a runtime error saying that the property I'm using can't be given a `decimal` value. I feel like the best I could do is detect the type mismatch myself at runtime and throw an only slightly better error instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use generic constraint. As struct type cannot be used directly, you can still use `IEquatable<T>` to limit what can be passed as `T`(built-in types implements this interface). Downside is that anything implementing `IEquatable<decimal>` will be allowed as `T` generic parameter(which may or not be issue in your case).

```
void DoSomething<T>(Expression<Func<Thing, T>> pDecimalExpression)
    where T : struct, IEquatable<decimal> {
    ...
}
```

---

Second option is to write custom Roslyn Analyzer to validate code during compile-time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've ultimately gone with this approach. I don't like making my methods needlessly generic, and I also had to work around converting between `T` and `decimal`, but this is better not having to write extra methods.

Comment: What exactly you were dealing with? I can take a look at it and hopefully give you an update to solve it.

Comment: I solved the conversion issue using the solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098316/621316

Comment: @DaveCousineau: I am sitting on it now. Just gimme me more context. You need to set the value only or there is something more to do?

Comment: I have no further issue. This is working great. I don't like these methods being generic, but it's definitely better than it was before. Everything works now, and if I provide an `int` property, I will get a compiler error.

Comment: If you are happy. I am glad. I just wanted to help with other possible scenarios that are there right from the beginning e.g. `DoSomething(t => t.GetDecimalProperty());`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a trick you can use. The compiler will prefer an overload with `int`, so provide it one and use the [`ObsoleteAttribute`'s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute) ability to emit a compile-time error.

Declare `DoSomething` like this:

```
void DoSomething(Expression<Func<Thing, decimal>> pDecimalExpression)
{
    // …
}

[Obsolete("No, no, no!", true)] // the true here causes an error instead of a warning
void DoSomething(Expression<Func<Thing, int>> pIntExpression)
{
    // just in case someone would call this method via reflection
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

and the following call causes a compile-time error:

```
DoSomething(t => t.IntProperty);
```

Comment: thanks! I thought of overloading, but only came up with either calling the other version which would still cast (if I could even call it), or just throwing an exception which is already what's happening.